# Need git script to copy changes from one branch to another

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a situation where one of my git repo has 50+ branches. if i make a change in one branch I will have to copy it to 50 others too. To do this I have been using the following commands

```
git checkout <branchA>
git cherry-pick <commit>
[solve conflicts if any]
[git cherry-pick --continue]
```

I want to automate this process using some sort of script.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I mean, it sounds like a weird thing to do. Are you sure that's really the problem you have to solve? Maybe, there's some more reasonable workflow to do what you intend. That said, if you really want to do this, I guess you have to write a shell (whatever shell you are using) script. I don't think git alone can do it.

Comment: How would the script know how to solve a conflict?